# Play 2.3, Git and IDEA: universal path to embedded database

Tags: git, playframework, sbt

My problem is to create the embedded database in project folder to share it with git. If I set an explicit path like:

```
C:/users/<user>/Projects/<project>
```

it works fine. But if somebody pulls the project from git, he gets wrong path. My idea is to set any universal path. If I try:

```
jdbc:h2:file:./db
```

the database is created in the folder /Program Files/IDEA/...

If I try:

```
jdbc:h2:file:~/db
```

the database is created in the folder /users/user/..., but not in folder of my project.

Is there any way to set the universal path of my project?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [H2's FAQ](http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#database_files) it should be without anything, no . or ~. So to store your database into your project's folder like `path_to_my_project/database/mydbfile` you can use:

```
 jdbc:h2:database/mydbfile
```

Comment: That depends. That FAQ says: "If the base directory is not set (as in jdbc:h2:test), the database files are stored in the directory where the application is started (the current working directory)"

Comment: Thanks, but it should be `jdbc:h2:file:database/mydbfile`

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues.  Upon seeing this I thought I'd have a look in the H2 source code. :)

So, if it has `~` then H2 replaces it with:

```
System.getProperty("User.home", "")
```

Then it passes the path straight to the ordinary Java `javax.io.File`.

So, given the above, you can craft the path that works for both of you.  Find a path for `javax.io.File` that would place it where you want it to.  If you want to use `~` then you know that it uses value set in `User.home` and if it's not defined, `""` is suffixed to the rest of the path.